# Securely send email from custom gsuit domain in python Django

Tags: python, django, smtp

I have two gsuit emails :

1. admin@mydomain.com -- this is the main admin
2. user@mydomain.com

I want to securely send email from user@mydomain.com using python3.7
I created app_password for `user@mydomain.com`  and tried the following code in Django:
settings.py:

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'user@mydomain.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

main function:

```
message = render_to_string('app1/email.html', {
            'fn': ip_dict['first_name'], 'ln': ip_dict['last_name']
        })


send_mail(
        'hello world',
        '',
        'user@mydomain.com',
        [ip_dict['email']],
        html_message=message,
    )
```

I get error :

```
SMTPAuthenticationError at /url/

(535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials v5sm4332617otk.64 - gsmtp')
```

With app_password the level of security is low. 
With google gmail API https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python the app opens a browser and makes me physically sign in. Is there any other secure way to send an email automatically from gmail .
Thanks

Comment: The link in the error message https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials gives steps to try.

Comment: I tried all those steps but it did not work. I have another normal gmail account user@gmail.com . It works with app_password.  Could there be something specific to gsuit accounts that I am missing?

Comment: @Aseem did you end up figuring this out?

Comment: Yes I will add a answer shortly.

Comment: @Aseem, could you please add your answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Detailed solution in a Jupyter notebook hosted on Gitlab:
[Link](https://gitlab.com/aseem.hegshetye/public-repository/-/blob/431772c8c5078ac11925a06ffb633268d3a85e67/Sending_email_with_gmail_API_securely.ipynb)